# Yii2:Does login,signup & password reset forms work together in single view

Tags: yii2

I am using yii2 for webapp. I got stuck at a very unique point & need help

I am using javascript fadeIn & Fadeout effect to show & hide the form. So to enable that effect i have to put all the three forms in a single view & have to call respective controllers(actionlogin, actionSignup & actionPasswordReset) on button click.

I declared rules for the parameters of all the three forms as 'required' for validation but when i submit the form, that time it is not working further as it wants me to fill the other two form fields as well to submit as the other two forms are also in the same view.

I also put my javascript code that call animation it is here:

```
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        App.setPage("login");  //Set current page
        App.init(); //Initialise plugins and elements
                                    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function swapScreen(id) {
            jQuery('.visible').removeClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
            jQuery('#' + id).addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
        }
    </script>
```

anyone knows how to do this

Code is:

```
<section id="login"  class="visible">
     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form', 'options' => array('role' => 'form')]); ?>
     <div class="form-group">
     <?= $form->field($model, 'email_address',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
     </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <?= $form->field($model, 'password', ['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-lock'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->passwordInput(); ?>
           </div>
           <div class="form-actions">
           <?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe',['template' => "{input}&nbsp;{label}"])->checkbox(); ?>
           <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
           </div>
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My signup page is

```
<section id="register" class="visible">

 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'signup-form',  'options' => array('role' => 'form')]); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'full_name',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-font'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <?= $form->field($model, 'email',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <?= $form->field($model, 'input_password',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-lock'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->passwordInput() ?>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <?= $form->field($model, 'input_confirm_password',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->passwordInput() ?>
      </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'agreeTC',['template' => "{input}"])->checkbox(['class' => 'uniform']); ?>                                       
        <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
          </div>
```

& my request reset code is:

```
<section id="forgot" class="visible">
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'request-password-reset-form']); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
       <?= $form->field($model, 'reset_email',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
       </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Send Me Reset Instructions', ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'name' => 'reset-button']) ?>   
         </div>
         <?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Could you include the view code?

Comment: My view code i am showing conceptually. It is too big so i have removed few things but its fine to give abstract idea.

Comment: I have given my javascript code before. I am calling it on the basis of id. I have removed the html code for div tags $ just shown the required code.

Comment: Can you add the form validation code of your controller as well? As I feel that May be where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola you could try this Make The Controller actionYourview() , instance 3 models and send to the view.
EXAMPLE controller

```
//your login,signup and passReset model dir 
use frontend\models\login;
use frontend\models\signup;
use frontend\models\passReset;

//example if the Controller is Site (defaulOne)
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    //your action
    public function actionYourview(){
    //1 Make your 3 models for separate

        $loginModel = new login();
        $signupModel = new signup();
        $passResetModel = new passReset();

        //this will solve your problem of the three forms as 'required' 
        if($loginModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  $loginModel){ //if Login form is summit and validate 
            //do your login stuff

        }else if($signupModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){ //if $signupModel form is summit 
            //do your signup stuff

        }else if($passResetModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){ //if $passreset form is summit 
            // do yout pass reset stuff
        }else{ // and else just render and make sure that you pass your 3 models

        return $this->render('Yourview',[
            'loginModelToView'           =>$loginModel,
            'signupModelToView'          =>$signupModel,
            'passResetModelToView'       =>$passResetModel
        ]);
        }
    }

}
```

and the view just change the $model to they respective model

login

```
<section id="login"  class="visible">
     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form', 'options' => array('role' => 'form')]); ?>
     <div class="form-group">
     <?= $form->field($loginModelToView, 'email_address',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
     </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <?= $form->field($loginModelToView, 'password', ['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-lock'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->passwordInput(); ?>
           </div>
           <div class="form-actions">
           <?= $form->field($loginModelToView, 'rememberMe',['template' => "{input}&nbsp;{label}"])->checkbox(); ?>
           <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
           </div>
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

signup

```
<section id="register" class="visible">

 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'signup-form',  'options' => array('role' => 'form')]); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
   <?= $form->field($signupModelToView, 'full_name',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-font'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <?= $form->field($signupModelToView, 'email',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <?= $form->field($signupModelToView, 'input_password',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-lock'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->passwordInput() ?>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <?= $form->field($signupModelToView, 'input_confirm_password',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"])->passwordInput() ?>
      </div>
       <div class="form-actions">
        <?= $form->field($signupModelToView, 'agreeTC',['template' => "{input}"])->checkbox(['class' => 'uniform']); ?>                                       
        <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
          </div>
```

finaly the reset

```
<section id="forgot" class="visible">
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'request-password-reset-form']); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
       <?= $form->field($passResetModelToView, 'reset_email',['template' => "{label}\n<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"]); ?>
       </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Send Me Reset Instructions', ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'name' => 'reset-button']) ?>   
         </div>
         <?php $form = ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

hope that this is what your looking. good luck

Comment: it works fine thanks for your reply....but when am getting logs in, my default layout is not getting applied what is happening with it??